# Getting wrong answer in search option

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in my main `Activity` and there is a search option in the `ActionBar`. But when I try to search something it gives me a wrong list.

This is my mainActivity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
FloatingActionButton fab;
DBHelper myDb;
ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList;
ListView listView;
RemainderAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myDb = new DBHelper(this);
    showViews();
    onClickViews();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityFour.class));
        }
    });
}

private void onClickViews() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int po, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityFive.class);
            i.putExtra("position", po);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

private void showViews() {
    rList = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
    rList = myDb.getAllRows();
    if (rList.size() != 0) {
        adapter = new RemainderAdapter(this, rList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"There is no item in the list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TextChange..." + newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUBMIT..." + query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        return true;
    }
};
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}}
```

//This is my DBHelper class

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DB_NAME = "my_db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "reminders_web";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String ACC_NAME = "a_name";
public static final String USER_NAME = "u_name";
public static final String PWD = "password";
public static final String WEB = "w_site";
public static final String DESC = "desc";

private SQLiteDatabase db;
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT," + ACC_NAME + " TEXT,"+USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + PWD + " TEXT," + WEB + " TEXT," + DESC + " TEXT "+ ")";
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String a_name,String u_name,String password,String web,String desc) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ACC_NAME,a_name);
    contentValues.put(USER_NAME,u_name);
    contentValues.put(PWD, password);
    contentValues.put(WEB, web);
    contentValues.put(DESC, desc);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    db.close();
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
public ArrayList<AccountDetails> getAllRows(){
    ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] col = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,ACC_NAME,USER_NAME,PWD,WEB,DESC};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, col, null, null, null, null, ACC_NAME);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AccountDetails details = new AccountDetails();

            details.setaName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ACC_NAME)));
            details.setuName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_NAME)));
            details.setPwd(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PWD)));
            details.setwSite(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WEB)));
            details.setDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESC)));

            rList.add(details);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return rList;
}

public boolean editRow(int id,String a_name, String u_name,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ACC_NAME,a_name);
    contentValues.put(USER_NAME,u_name);
    contentValues.put(PWD, password);
    long result=db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, KEY_ROWID + "="+id, null);
    db.close();
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public void deleteRow(AccountDetails rDetails) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ACC_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rDetails.getaName())});
    db.close();
}}
```

//this is my custom Adapter class

```
    public class RemainderAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private Context context;
int i=0;
private ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList;
private TextView aName,uName,circle;
ArrayList<AccountDetails> suggArray= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
private ArrayList<AccountDetails> originalData = null;
RemainderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rList = rList;
    this.suggArray = rList;
    this.originalData=rList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return suggArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        aName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aName);
        uName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uName);
        circle=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circle);
    }
    aName.setText(suggArray.get(position).getaName().toString());
    uName.setText(suggArray.get(position).getuName().toString());
    circle.setText(suggArray.get(position).getaName().toString().substring(0, 1));
    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

public Filter mFilter  = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final ArrayList<AccountDetails> nlist = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();

        String filterableString ;

        for (AccountDetails accountDetails : rList ) {
            filterableString = accountDetails.getaName().toString();
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                Log.e("Values", "Model Value : "+filterableString + "  , String Value : " + constraint);
                nlist.add(accountDetails);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        suggArray = (ArrayList<AccountDetails>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Wrong list? Please be more specific about the problem. You might consider sharing what you want and what do you get. Remove un necessary parts from your code.

Comment: what type result you are getting? isn't the result from the criteria you search for?

Comment: whatever i am trying to search it always shows the 1st one in the list(rList).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some logical problem here .

1. You overwriting your main List `rList`. You need to declare a separate suggestion list for that.
2. you declare the nlist as the same size of your main list .  `final ArrayList<AccountDetails> nlist = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>(originalData.size());`
3. you using the index `i` which should not be the valid position. `originalData.get(i)`;

So it will be like this .

***Solution***

**1st**

Declear a new `ArrayList` of `AccountDetails`. `ArrayList<AccountDetails> suggArray= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();` Al replace `rList` by `suggArray` for everywhere in the adapter(Except the Constructor).

**2nd**

`ArrayList<AccountDetails> suggArray= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();`

**3rd**

Cahnge the loop like this way.

```
for (AccountDetails accountDetails : rList ) {
      filterableString = accountDetails.getaName().toString();
      if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
            nlist.add(new AccountDetails(accountDetails.getaName().toString(),accountDetails.getuName().toString(),
                    accountDetails.getPwd().toString(),accountDetails.getwSite().toString(),accountDetails.getDesc().toString()));
      }
 }
```

Finally it looks like this .

```
public class RemainderAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList;
    private TextView aName,uName;
    ArrayList<AccountDetails> suggArray= new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();
    private ArrayList<AccountDetails> originalData = null;
    RemainderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AccountDetails> rList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rList = rList;
        this.suggArray = rList;
        this.originalData=rList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return suggArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return suggArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            aName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aName);
            uName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uName);
        }
        aName.setText(suggArray.get(position).getaName().toString());
        uName.setText(suggArray.get(position).getuName().toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    public Filter mFilter  = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final ArrayList<AccountDetails> nlist = new ArrayList<AccountDetails>();

        String filterableString ;

        for (AccountDetails accountDetails : rList ) {
            filterableString = accountDetails.getaName().toString();
            Log.e("Values","Model Value : "filterableString +"  , String Value : "+constraint); // Check Here
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(accountDetails);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        suggArray = (ArrayList<AccountDetails>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: @diya , Did you try this ?

Comment: Thank u @ Zahidul Islam for your response , i tried with this code.but now my initial ListView is empty.B'coz initially suggArray is empty. Data stored in  rList,but we are tring to show the data from  suggArray.pls check it once again and give suggestion.

Comment: @diya , This is pretty simple , Just in the constructor assign the `suggArray = rList` . Check my updated code .

Comment: @ Zahidul Islam,i tried .now search option does not work

Comment: @diya , the process is ok, Check your data set .

Comment: @ Zahidul, i checked several times but didn't find the problem in data set.pls help

Comment: @ Zahidul, internally search option doing well but displays another(wrong) list.i have sent all codes.pls check and suggest me what wrong i did in my code

Comment: @ Zahidul, did u check my codes which i edited in my previous code?

Comment: @diya , please debug your code . Process is OK, so if there are any issue related data. You have to find it out .

Comment: @ Zahidul,i am puzzled,did not find out..pls help

Comment: @ Zahidul,finally i got the accurate search list.now another problem arise.when i click any item from the searched list for details,previous item on that position has come

Comment: @diya , First of all Congratulation to solve your problem. Now, Try by yourself , i hope you will solve it too by yourself .

Comment: @ Zahidul,thank u..but credit  goes to u..i am trying to find out the 2nd problem

Comment: @diya, you welcome. You can accept my answer and put a upvote :)

Comment: @ Zahidul,I have an action bar containing a searchview..when search button is clicked,action bar shows a back button on the left side.if i click this back button , searchview. and back button disappear but the listView shows only searched list not original list. how can i solve this to find the original list when i click back button or onBackPressed.